# Wordpress Wrap Every 2 Post in a div

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to wrap every 2 post in a div "row-fluid" Right now my HTML looks like the following...

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="odd-post span6"></div>
   <div class="even-post span6"></div>
   <div class="odd-post span6"></div>
   <div class="even-post span6"></div>
 </div>
```

I'd like it to look like this...

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="odd-post span6"></div>
   <div class="even-post span6"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="odd-post span6"></div>
   <div class="even-post span6"></div>
 </div>
```

This is the php that I'm using to generate this but I think because I'm counting outside of my loop its not rendering the way I'd like it too.

```
                <?php
                    $count = 0;
                    if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
                        $open = !($count%2) ? '<div class="row-fluid">' : '';
                        $close = !($count%2) && $count ? '</div>' : '';
                    echo $close.$open;
                ?>


                <!--Custom Post Type Boilerplate-->
                <?php

                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'mysite_team', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                    echo '<div ';
                        $even_odd = (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'featured-image-wrapper-even-post span6' : 'featured-image-wrapper-odd-post span6'; post_class( $even_odd );
                    echo '>';

                    echo '<h1>';
                    echo '<a href="';
                        the_permalink();
                    echo '">';
                        the_title();
                    echo '</a></h1>';


                    echo '<div class="featured-image alignleft">';
                    echo '<a href="';
                        the_permalink();
                    echo '">';
                        the_post_thumbnail('team-thumbnail-size');
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '</div>';


                    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
                        the_excerpt();
                    echo '<p><a href="';
                        the_permalink();
                    echo '"><i>Read More';
                    echo '</i></a></p>';
                    echo '</div>';

                    echo '</div>';

                endwhile;

                ?>

                <?php
                    $count++;
                    endwhile;
                    else :
                ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $count ? '</div>' : ''; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm starting to see circle and get confused. 
Thank you!

Comment: First, you are generating invalid html. You cannot have `<div>` and `<h1>` wrapped in an `<a>` tag as they are block elements. Second, there's a closing `</h1>` without a matching opening `<h1>`. Could you post the actual output of your code snippet?

Comment: Okay I've fixed this problem. Sorry about that. Nice catch!

Comment: I think this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247770/loop-through-wordpress-posts-and-wrap-each-x-post-in-a-div/

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the extra div container, sorry. You can solve this with pure CSS.

```
.row-fluid:nth-child(odd) {
// Some code
}
.row-fluid:nth-child(even) {
// Some code
}
.span6 {
width:50%;
display:inline-cell;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: i thought about that but then i'm over-riding bootstrap which seems weird.