# Loop through WordPress posts, and wrap each X post in a DIV

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, modulo

**Note: This is a self Q&A**

When building asymmetrical grid layouts in WordPress, it's common that you'd want to wrap each X post in a div, like so:

```
div
    post
    post
/div
div
    post
    post
/div
div
    post
    post
/div
```

I'd like to avoid using a modulo operator as it gets confusing quickly.

Comment: Why is amodulo operator confusing? That is very common and straightforward approach to this.

Comment: You have to keep track the count, you have to have a bunch of if/else to make sure the wrapping divs don't get left open and/or the first one is created correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most people do this with a modulo operator, but it gets awkward to do it if no posts are found, or and even division occurs on the last post. I've expanded on the [answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753786/php-adding-divs-to-a-foreach-loop-every-4-times) by @The Shift Exchange to do it in a cleaner way.

```
<?php
    // Get posts (tweak args as needed)
    $args = array(
        'post_type'        => 'page',
        'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'post_parent'      => $post->ID,
        'order'            => 'ASC'
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
?>

<?php foreach (array_chunk($posts, 2, true) as $posts) :  ?>

    <div class="row">

        <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <a id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You would change the "2" in the first foreach loop to be the amount you want grouped per row.

Comment: Woah. I've always used modulo but this is much cleaner. Very nice!