# In WordPress loop, how do I check how many post have been looped through?

Tags: wordpress, loops

My goal is to print some extra html,  after every four posts.

What is wrong with the following code

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    <?php
        $posts = $wp_query->post_count;

        if ( $posts == 4 ) {
            echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        }
    ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through WordPress posts, and wrap each X post in a DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247770/loop-through-wordpress-posts-and-wrap-each-x-post-in-a-div)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking the basic code of [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), you could include a counter, increment it on every iteration and check if its zero module four.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : $count = 1; ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>    
    <!-- do stuff ... -->
    <?php if ( $count % 4 == 0 ): ?>
        <!-- extra stuff every four posts -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $count++; endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this question has already been answered, but I think there are cleaner ways of doing this.

You have several useful properties in the WP_Query object you could use, instead of having to add custom incrementers.

```
<?php
// Do not forget this part, required if you do not define a custom WP_Query
global $wp_query;

// Below you can find some useful properties in the WP_Query object
// Use them to their full potential

// Gets filled with the requested posts from the database.  
echo $wp_query->posts;

// The number of posts being displayed. 
echo $wp_query->post_count;

// The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters 
echo $wp_query->found_posts;

// The total number of pages. Is the result of $found_posts / $posts_per_page 
echo $wp_query->max_num_pages;

// Index of the post currently being displayed. (Can only be used within the loop)
while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo $wp_query->current_post;
endwhile;
```

Your loop would look like this, while using the $current_post property.

```
<?php global $wp_query; ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    <?php
        if ( ( $wp_query->current_post + 1 ) % 4 === 0 ) {
            echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        }
    ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

I believe this to be a good and clean solution.

Read more about the WP_Query object here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
<?php 
$count = 1;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); 
    if ( $count%4==0 ) {
        echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
    }
    $count++;
endwhile;  ?>
```

Comment: thanks, you have syntax errors, line 4, other wise works great. Thanks again.

Comment: there were ? symbol left after ; just need to remove that

Comment: Yes, I corrected that and both of the solutions works.
Yours is better and simple.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a bug in the answers before mine: it echoes the "closing" tag at the end of every fourth post - but **what if the post count is 5?** (Or any other number not divisible by 4? Of course the need for solving this problem may vary from HTML to HTML.)

Look at this example with 5:

--post 1--
--post 2--
--post 3--
--post 4--
--closing tag--
--post 5--
??????

You can see that after the 5th post the loop is not closed with the closing tag.

Therefore I would suggest using this code (that takes the number of posts or the number of posts_per_page in account):

```
<?php
    // taking @Jordi Nebot's code from his answer - thank you
    if ( have_posts() ) : $count = 1;
?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>    
    <!-- do stuff ... -->
    <?php
        // the conditions in the if are triggered after every 4th post
        // OR if all the posts have been echoed OR all the posts for 
        // this page have been echoed
        if ( $count % 4 == 0 || $wp_query->found_posts == $count || $wp_query->posts_per_page == $count ):
    ?>
        <!-- extra stuff every four posts -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $count++; endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This could be a real concern (I sometimes use a `$opened` boolean var to check if any tag is opened after the loop) but in this case, OP's echoing `<div class="clearfix"></div>`, so there's no chance for unclosed tags as far as I understand...

Comment: You are right, that the tags are closed - that's why I wrote that "the need for solving this problem..." - we do not know, whether the HTML (the site layout) "needs" that clearfix at the end. The look of the site may fall apart without it - or there may be no need for it at all. I supposed that most of the time clearfix is needed after some float elements - and without clearing things up ("closing the float") the next element may not behave as expected.